# How to eliminate non-working hours in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have two columns of DateTime type. The first one stores the DateTime when a process it started, the other one stores the DateTime when that process is finished. I want to calculate the total working hours put in to complete the work. The working hours are 10 am to 7 pm and Sundays are off.

Here are a few snippets that I've jotted down:

```
       SELECT col1, col2, floor(((date2-date1)*24*60*60)/3600)
       || ' HOURS ' ||
       floor((((date2-date1)*24*60*60) -
       floor(((date2-date1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)
       || ' MINUTES ' ||
       round((((date2-date1)*24*60*60) -
       Floor(((date2-date1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600 -
       (floor((((date2-date1)*24*60*60) -
       floor(((date2-date1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)*60) ))
       || ' SECS ' Time_Difference
       From Table_Name;
```

And,

```
       Select To_Number(To_Char(date1, 'HH24')) || ':'
       ||   to_number(to_char(date1, 'MI')) || ':'||
       to_number(to_char(date1, 'SS')) from Table_Name
```

Please help.

---

To the above solution you have mentioned, this is the result!

```
START DATE          DAY     FINISH DATE     DAY  Date Diff   Total Hours   Work Hours 

07-AUG-12 21:55:21  TUE 08-AUG-12 11:09:10  WED 0 13:13:49.0        13   13 
13-NOV-12 15:45:25  TUE 14-NOV-12 10:41:42  WED 0 18:56:17.0        18   18 
20-DEC-12 20:31:03  THU 21-DEC-12 11:03:36  FRI 0 14:32:33.0        14   14 
14-MAR-13 20:39:00  THU 15-MAR-13 11:00:04  FRI 0 14:21:4.0         14   14 
07-JUN-12 21:17:36  THU 08-JUN-12 11:02:23  FRI 0 13:44:47.0        13   13 
18-SEP-12 20:48:27  TUE 19-SEP-12 11:07:35  WED 0 14:19:8.0         14   14
```

New Scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248741/how-to-get-business-hours-between-two-dates-in-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to calculate the difference between the start and finish date excluding the time before 10 am and after 7 pm.

Here's the sample query and [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c1e2/3).

```
SELECT start_time,
       finish_time,
       interval_time,
       EXTRACT (HOUR FROM interval_time), --extract the hours,mins and seconds from the interval
       EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM interval_time),
       EXTRACT (SECOND FROM interval_time)
  FROM (SELECT start_time,
               finish_time,
               NUMTODSINTERVAL (
                    CASE
                       WHEN finish_time - TRUNC (finish_time) > (19 / 24) --if finish time is after 7pm
                       THEN
                          TRUNC (finish_time) + (19 / 24)      --set it to 7pm
                       ELSE
                          finish_time      --else set it to actual finish time
                    END
                  - CASE
                       WHEN start_time - TRUNC (start_time) < (10 / 24) --if start time is before 10 am
                       THEN
                          TRUNC (start_time) + (10 / 24)    --set it to 10 am.
                       ELSE
                          start_time    --else set it to the actual start time
                    END,
                  'day') --subtract the both and convert the resulting day to interval
                  interval_time
          FROM timings);
```

What I have done is,

- Check if the start time is before 10 am and finish time is after 7 pm. If so, set the time to 10 am and 7 pm.
- Then subtract the dates and convert the resulting days to Interval Type.
- Then extract the hours, mins and seconds from the Interval.

**Note:** This query assumes that both dates fall on same day and both are not before 10am or after 7 pm.

**UPDATE:**
To exclude holidays, the query will become complicated. I suggest writing three functions and use these functions in the query.

*1st function:*

```
FUNCTION modify_start_time (p_in_dte DATE) RETURN DATE
----------------------------------
IF p_in_dte - TRUNC (p_in_dte) < (10 / 24)
THEN
   RETURN TRUNC (p_in_dte) + (10 / 24);
ELSIF p_in_dte - TRUNC (p_in_dte) > (19 / 24)
THEN
   RETURN TRUNC (p_in_dte) + 1 + (10 / 24);
ELSE
   RETURN p_in_dte;
END IF;
```

If the start time is outside the work hours, modify the start time to next nearest start time.

*2nd function:*

```
FUNCTION modify_finish_time (p_in_dte DATE) RETURN DATE
----------------------------------
IF p_in_dte - TRUNC (p_in_dte) > (19 / 24)
THEN
   RETURN TRUNC (p_in_dte) + (19 / 24);
ELSIF p_in_dte - TRUNC (p_in_dte) < (10 / 24)
THEN
   RETURN TRUNC (p_in_dte) - 1 + (19 / 24);
ELSE
   RETURN p_in_dte;
END IF;
```

If the finish time is outside the work hours, modify it to the previous nearest finish time.

*3rd function:*

```
FUNCTION get_days_to_exclude (p_in_start_date     DATE,
                              p_in_finish_date    DATE) RETURN NUMBER
--------------------------------------------------------
WITH cte --get all days between start and finish date
     AS (    SELECT p_in_start_date + LEVEL - 1 dte
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= p_in_finish_date + 1 - p_in_starT_date)
SELECT COUNT (1) * 9 / 24    --mutiply the days with work hours in a day
  INTO l_num_holidays
  FROM cte
 WHERE    TO_CHAR (dte, 'dy') = 'sun'    --find the count of sundays
       OR dte IN     --fins the count of holidays, assuming leaves are stored in separate table
             (SELECT leave_date  
                FROM leaves
               WHERE leave_date BETWEEN p_in_start_date
                                    AND p_in_finish_date);

l_num_holidays :=
   l_num_holidays + ( (p_in_finish_date - p_in_start_date) * (15 / 24)); --also, if the dates span more than a day find the non working hours.

RETURN l_num_holidays;
```

This function finds the no of days to be excluded while calculating the duration.

So, the final query should be something like this,

```
SELECT start_time,
       finish_time,
       CASE
          WHEN work_duration < 0 THEN NUMTODSINTERVAL (0, 'day')
          ELSE NUMTODSINTERVAL (work_duration, 'day')
       END
  FROM (SELECT start_time, finish_time,
               --modify_start_time (start_time), modify_finish_time (finish_time),
                 modify_finish_time (finish_time)
               - modify_start_time (start_time)
               - get_days_to_exclude (
                    TRUNC (modify_start_time (start_time)),
                    TRUNC (modify_finish_time (finish_time)))
                  work_duration
          FROM timings);
```

If the duration is less than 0, ignore it by setting it to 0.

Comment: And what to do when a SUNDAY or a holiday falls between the two dates. How do we exclude those hours?

Comment: I've edited and uploaded the sample data you asked for. And yes, start and finish date can span more than one day. For instance, when the start date is on Saturday and the finish date is on Monday then the date difference spans more than a day!

Answer (score 0):

You can take the hour difference between the two dates and reduce the amount of non-working hours times the days between the two days. 
consider this example :

```
create table t1 (
    start_hour date , finish_hour date);

insert into t1 values (
  to_date('01/01/2013 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  to_date('01/01/2013 15:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

insert into t1 values (
  to_date('01/01/2013 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  to_date('02/01/2013 15:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

insert into t1 values (
  to_date('01/01/2013 18:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  to_date('03/01/2013 11:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));


with x as (
select start_hour ,finish_hour , 
      (finish_hour - start_hour) * 24 hour_diff , 
       trunc(finish_hour) - trunc(start_hour) as day_diff
from t1
) 
select  start_hour , finish_hour , 
        hour_diff - 15 * day_diff as working_hours 
from x;

|                     START_HOUR |                    FINISH_HOUR | WORKING_HOURS |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| January, 01 2013 12:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2013 15:00:00+0000 |             3 |
| January, 01 2013 12:00:00+0000 | January, 02 2013 15:00:00+0000 |            12 |
| January, 01 2013 18:00:00+0000 | January, 03 2013 11:00:00+0000 |            11 |
```