# Oracle SQL - How to work out the working hours and minutes between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, clock

Is there a way in Oracle SQL of finding out the number of WORKING hours and minutes between two dates?

As an example

The working day is Monday - Fri  8am-5pm

```
Job.Job_Logged     Job.Actual_Start_Date       Time Elapsed
01/08/2019 10:00   01/08/2019  12:32           2:32
01/08/2019 16:00   02/08/2019  09:00           3:00
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @HereGoes The possible duplicate you referenced relates to just normal hours and minutes between two times - I'm looking for specifically WORKING hours.

Comment: @Jeff Holt - no not tried anything yet.  Not even sure where to start with it to be honest.

Comment: Another [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17120922/266304).

Comment: In the example they find the difference in days and then multiple by the number of hours in a day.  Their day has 24hrs, your day has x hrs.  Change the calculation to multiple by length of your day  instead of 24.  Concept seems to be the same.

Comment: I'm for Alex Poole's duplicate citation.

Comment: @JeffHolt: agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check for possible duplicates, but one way to do it is recursive query:

```
with cte(id, start_date, end_date, hd1, hd2) as (
    select id, cast(start_date as date), cast(end_date as date), cast(start_date as date), 
           cast(least(end_date, trunc(start_date) + 17/24) as date)
      from jobs 
    union all 
    select id, start_date, end_date, cast(trunc(hd1) + 1 + 8/24 as date), 
           cast(least(trunc(hd1) + 1 + 17/24, end_date) as date)
      from cte
      where trunc(hd1) + 1 + 8/24 < end_date)
select id, start_date, end_date, dbms_xplan.format_time_s(sum(hd2 - hd1) * 24 * 60) hours
  from cte
  where to_char(hd1, 'd') not in (6, 7)
  group by id, start_date, end_date
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f856232a6335d2dcdf0af7427ce65ba5)</sup>**

Where I use `17/24` it means ending hour `17:00`, `8/24` - starting hour, `not in (6, 7)` excludes saturdays and sundays.

**Edit 1:** It should be 24 * 60 * 60 in last select.

**Edit 2:** To make query independent of nls_settings use:

```
to_char(hd1, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fabe8fd06ac314bc3b90e9b99640046)</sup>**

---

> the version of Oracle I'm using insists on having SELECT as the first
>   word in any code

Such recursive queries are available from Oracle version 11. I don't know if your tool requires `select` in the first line or is this version problem, but in first case you can move RCTE to `from` clause:

```
select id, start_date, end_date, dbms_xplan.format_time_s(sum(hd2 - hd1) * 24 * 60 * 60) hours
  from (
    with
      cte(id, start_date, end_date, hd1, hd2) as (
        select id, cast(start_date as date), cast(end_date as date), cast(start_date as date),
               cast(least(end_date, trunc(start_date) + 17/24) as date)
          from jobs
        union all
        select id, start_date, end_date, cast(trunc(hd1) + 1 + 8/24 as date),
               cast(least(trunc(hd1) + 1 + 17/24, end_date) as date)
          from cte
          where trunc(hd1) + 1 + 8/24 < end_date)
     select * from cte 
       where to_char(hd1, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('Sat', 'Sun') )
  group by id, start_date, end_date
```

**<sup>[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6061f0f5be430ce22b67254f62552880)</sup>**

Comment: You need to be careful with day numbers as they depend on NLS territory - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a52fcb0fdeb060f8a6f45831f6793c9). I'm not sure why the answer for ID 2 differs though; it should be 2 hours though, right? I'm not sure why it's only 1 in your original. (Even [after your edit](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffc266bcf2f0bfd40e99710ff6f95334).)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, nls_territory is important. And yes, 2 hours, 16-17 and 8-9.

Comment: Thanks for this but the version of Oracle I'm using insists on having SELECT as the first word in any code.

Comment: @RobMorris - the version of Oracle (i.e. pre-9i), or the client/application you are using? If the latter you might be able to wrap the whole thing in a `select * from ( ... )` hack. If the former then you can use a hierarchical query (in an inline view) instead of the recursive CTE. (It's helpful to include any restrictions in your question...)

Comment: I think its more the application that it is being used in (Confirm) as the version is 11g.

I've tried looking online for how to create an inline view from a CTE but it's showing nothing and the previous example looks nothing like this one in terms of syntax

Comment: As you can see in the fiddles both queries works and we do not know your application.

Comment: Thank you @PonderStibbons - thats got it working now.  I'm trying to get to grips with Oracle and finding some things a lot easier than others!